# How to send message to Telegram from HTML page

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, telegram

I've made a stupid site that, among all the things, gives a random name from a given set of names and does it by popping up a modal containing the name and a gif. 
Now, how to share the content of the modal? 
I'd love to send via telegram the name and the gif but I don't really know how to do it... 
If it helps: I've also made a telegram bot using php (and deployed on heroku)...

Comment: I didn't get you :(.     Do you mean let user send message to Telegram by clicking button on HTML page?

Comment: well sort of. I got a pop-up/modal that contains a label and an image. I'd like to share those elements like you do on native apps (think about the Share button of youtube or any other apps but implemented in html5 or js)